# Convergence almost surely of $a_nX$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a random variable and $\{a_n\}$ is a real sequence converging to 0 as $n\to \infty$. It's clear to me that if $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i^2<\infty$ then the sequence formed by $a_nX$ converges almost surely to zero. What if this last condition is not satisfied? I can't prove either convergence almost surely neither find a counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean by "the sequence formed by $a_n X$"? Is every $a_n$ multiplied by a different trial of $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Use
$$a_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
$$X\sim \text{Geo}(0.5)$$
as a counterexample.